# Write a book in an old format

Tags: book-design, document

I plan to write a small math book but I am a beginner in `LaTeX`. I have written articles, but it is the first time that I will write a book. I would like your help if there is any information that will help me with the design I am looking for.

The idea that I have is related to the models of old books, specifically in the part of the chapters. I attach an image so that the idea is understood.

[image]

Comment: Welcome. // From a Latex point of view there isn't much difference in writing books or articles: you only need minor adjustments on the hierarchie of chapters (see tag document). // Though this isn't your font, have a look here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60360/how-to-use-fraktur-gothic-fonts-in-text-mode/60366#60366, follow Related links, enter own serch terms on top of this page. // Find more on the book-structure here https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure#Book_structure . // Why did you tag bookmarks?

Comment: thank you very much for the information // Why tag bookmarks? , I wanted to tag book design but it didn't allow me

Comment: Not math, but have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24719

Comment: oh great, thank you very much

Comment: Some helpful spirit already corrected your tag. Just click on it and follow where it leads you.